# PERL: Comparing two arrays with Regex and a nested foreach not working

Tags: regex, arrays, perl, nested, compare

I am having trouble with a PERL Script I'm writing to take 1 smaller file and compare each line with the contents of a larger file.  I am using a positive look-behind regex statement to find the match and give me just the rest of the line.

When I run the code I see all of the elements of @elements print, with no matches printed until the last line.  Without displaying sensitive data this is what I see.

$element[0]

.

.

.

$element[30]

[match]

.

.

.

.

.

The matches for element[30] list perfectly, but I am expecting this to happen for each element, not just last element in the array.  Here is my code:

```
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    open(my $in, "<", "call_types.txt");
    my @elements = <$in>;
    close $in;
    open(my $in, "<", "DNIS.cfg");
    my @dnis = <$in>;
    close $in;

    foreach my $call(@elements){
        print "$call\n";
        foreach my $dn(@dnis){
            if($dn =~ /(?<=$call ).*/){ 
                 print "$&\n";
            }
        }
        print "\n";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to

```
chomp @elements
```

before you use the contents, otherwise the contents will match only if the text appears at the end of lines in `@dnis`.

There is also no point in using a look-behind, and you need to be careful of any regex metacharacters the data may contain. You probably need

```
print "$1\n" if $dn =~ /(\Q$call\E.*)/;
```

Comment: thank you very much!  Chomping the array worked, and thanks for the tip on escaping the variable.  I didn't even consider the fact that the variable could contain inadvertent regex commands.